# Saving General Yang Animals Harmed?

Tags: stunts, saving-general-yang

Were animals harmed during the making of Saving General Yang (2013)?

There are scenes where horses stumble and fall on their necks, are shot with arrows, slashed with swords, jump through fire, and fall on people. Are these stunts or computer animated, or were animals actually injured during the making of the film? A citation (one way or another) would be of great help.

Comment: If you don't have the rep to create a tag, please don't tag a completely unrelated film, instead apply a relevant "generic" tag and ask in a comment for other users to create and add the proper tag. https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/278/13595

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the movie credits... **"No animals were harmed"**

[image]